# I can not open file with partial file name on vba

Tags: excel, vba

just few days ago, i can open workbook with partial file name.

but today, i tried this code several times and he's still saying 1004 error

why?

```
Sub open_data_workbook()


Dim myPath As String
Dim main_workbook As String
Dim data_workbook As String
Dim xlsxm As String
Dim code_name As String

With ActiveSheet
    code_name = Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    xlsxm = ".xlsx"
    data_workbook = "*" & code_name & "*" & xlsxm
    main_workbook = "EMS-Part Data.xlsm"
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & data_workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Dir` to turn a wildcard string into an actual filename to open, because wildcards imply that there can be multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Open Workbook

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub open_data_workbook()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim main_workbook As String
    Dim data_workbook As String
    Dim xlsxm As String
    Dim code_name As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        code_name = .Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        xlsxm = ".xlsx"
        data_workbook = Dir("*" & code_name & "*" & xlsxm)
        If data_workbook = "" Then
            MsgBox "File not found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        main_workbook = "EMS-Part Data.xlsm"
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & data_workbook
    
End Sub
```