# Search for and open Word file with partial name

Tags: excel, vba, search

In Excel, I'd like to open a .docx file from a specific folder that I know only a part of the name of the file. That folder can contain several files with that part of name, so I need that after the inputbox asks me which partial name I need, a dialog box shows me all files that meet partial name criteria and let me choose which one I want to open.

I expect that after a button is pressed:

- an inputbox asks me the partial name I need
- a dialog box shows me a list of files that meet the criteria from a specific folder (always the same)
- after the file is selected and double clicked from the dialog box, this file opens in MS Word.

My code goes fine until I have to select and open selected file:

```vb
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim sFileName As String, sFullName As String
    Dim Res As Long
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim arrFile As Variant
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sStr As String, aStr As String
    Dim i As Long, ictr As Long, iPos As Long
    Dim sMsg As String, iButtons As Long, sTitle As String
    Dim X As String
    Dim searchname As String
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim strFile As String
    'Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Const sPercorso As String = _
                    "mypath"        '<<=== Modifica
    Const sFileMask As String = "2022"              '<<=== Modifica
    Const ast As String = "*"
    Const astext As String = "*.docx"

    With Application
        Set fd = .FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        sStr = .PathSeparator
    End With

    If Right(sPercorso, 1) = sStr Then
        sPath = sPercorso
    Else
        sPath = sPercorso & sStr
    End If
        X = InputBox("Nome file?")
        searchname = ast & X & astext
    With fd
        .Title = "Seleziona i files di interesse"
        .Filters.Add "File docx", "*.docx", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = sPath
        .InitialFileName = searchname                '"*.docx"
        Res = .Show
        If Res Then
            With .SelectedItems
               ictr = .Count
               ReDim arrFile(1 To ictr)
               For i = 1 To ictr
                   sFullName = Trim(.Item(i))
                   iPos = InStrRev(sFullName, aStr)
                   sFileName = Mid(sFullName, iPos + 1)
                   arrFile(i) = sFileName
               Next i
             End With
             aStr = Join(arrFile, vbNewLine)
             sMsg = "Dalla cartella " _
                 & sPercorso _
                 & " i seguenti file sono stati selezionati:" _
                 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                 & aStr
            iButtons = vbInformation
            sTitle = "REPORT"
         Else
           sMsg = "Hai cancellato la selezione!"
           iButtons = vbCritical
           sTitle = "SELEZIONE CANCELLATO"
        End If
        Call MsgBox( _
             Prompt:=sMsg, _
             Buttons:=iButtons, _
             Title:=sTitle)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the *specific problem* you're having while trying to make this work?  We're here to help you with *your code*, not write it for you.

Comment: Previously Answered question [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630520/i-can-not-open-file-with-partial-file-name-on-vba) - You might just need to change it a little for ms word.

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry for that, my coding is so bad I was ashamed to post it

Comment: Why not just ask the user to pick the one file using the FileDialog?  Your description mentions one file but you have `.AllowMultiSelect = True` and then some code to load the selected files into an array.  Your code doesn't seem to match your description...

Comment: @TimWilliams ok I can easily switch .AllowMultiSelect to false, but that is not the point. I tried to adapt some code that seems to me fit my task, but it does fit only until a certain point, and I don't know how to pass the variable of the file selected to openfile. I need the search part because there are several files with part of the name in common and I need to select one of them among hundreds in a fast way. Please just hint me after  search and select, how can I open it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Public Sub Tester()
    Const sPercorso As String = "C:\Temp\SO\"   '<<=== Modifica
    
    Dim sFileName As String, sPath As String, pathSep As String, X As String
    Dim searchname As String, objWord As Object, objDoc As Object
    
    pathSep = Application.PathSeparator
    sPath = sPercorso & IIf(Right(sPercorso, 1) = pathSep, "", pathSep)
    
    X = InputBox("Nome file?")
    searchname = "*" & X & "*.docx"
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .title = "Seleziona i files di interesse"
        .Filters.Add "File docx", "*.docx", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False '<<<<<<<
        .InitialFileName = sPath
        .InitialFileName = searchname
        
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            objWord.Visible = True
            Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Open(sFileName)
            AppActivate objWord.Caption 'show the Word window
            '...work with objDoc
        Else
           MsgBox "Hai cancellato la selezione!", vbCritical, "SELEZIONE CANCELLATO"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I sang victory too soon, actually it work fine and open the required doc, but in the end I have this message: "runtime error 5 invalid procedure or argument call" and VBA highlight the following instruction: "AppActivate objWord.Caption".

Comment: Try `objWord.Activate` instead